# DescribeCluster returning 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-eks

I'm creating a cluster with eksctl using a set of credentials.  I'm then using those same credentials statically to describe the cluster.  Snippet of code below

It works in us-west-1 region.  But I tried another region which is Singapore and it failed.

```
// ...
svc := eks.NewFromConfig(cfg)
cluster, err := svc.DescribeCluster(context.TODO(), &eks.DescribeClusterInput{Name: aws.String(name)})
if err != nil {
   // Error returned here:  
    return nil, err
}
```

This is the content from err.

> DescribeCluster, https response error StatusCode: 404, RequestID:
> 7172ae86-b234-4d40-b457-e17ce9c94f0b, ResourceNotFoundException: No
> cluster found for name: matt-test2.

404 seems to indicate a permissions error.  Maybe using the static credentials accessKeyId, secretKeyId is not the right way?  would love some pointers on IAM it's very complicated and I feel like a complete beginner

Answer (score 0):

`No cluster found` is not a permission error. You can get the same error when doing `aws eks describe-cluster --name matt-test2 --region ap-southeast-1 --profile <awscli named profile>` with a non-existence cluster name or wrong region. If you can get the aws cli working, your golang program will work with the same profile.

Comment: I created the cluster with `eksctl create cluster --name matt-test2 --region ap-southeast-1` 
But I'm using golang sdk to call DescribeCluster with the same static credentaials.

Comment: If you use cli as described; do you get the same error? Note Golang or CLI, they make same call underthehood.